# Spine: export both skeleton and spritesheet

Tags: spritesheet, spine

I am follow this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/54511/2d-skeletal-animation-with-spine-tutorial) for animation using spine. In this tutorial, they are import components separately (i.e: head, body, hands, legs ...). After I finish animation part, I want to export to json. After export to json, I check content, I see this:

```
{
"skeleton": {
    "hash": "3EPAHc7vcP4zQ93w+eSLhR5M6YQ",
    "spine": "3.6.53",
    "width": 205.5,
    "height": 506.79,
    "images": "../../Downloads/SpineElf_START/"
},
```

I see that images path is absolutely. Moreover, they are using images separately based on file name.

```
"lArm": {
            "lArm": { "x": 59.26, "y": 8.91, "rotation": 76.18, "width": 69, "height": 142 }
        },
```

I want to use spritesheet. I don't have much experience in this field. So my question is: We will import spritesheet from very first time start project or there is an option in spine that allow export json file + spritesheet.

Thanks

Comment: What are you ultimately importing the animation into?

Comment: I am using Pixij.JS framework :D